# Install root certificate on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, svn, certificates

Does anybody know how to install root certificate on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit? All methods I've found in Internet don't work (`update-ca-certificate`, `dpkg-reconfigure` etc.). In my previous Ubuntu installation (12.04) there was no problem. Also no problems with debian. I need this for example to checkout svn repo which is located under URL: https://svn.mydomain.com/. SSL Cert for mydomain is signed by my CA (ActiveDirectory).

There was a topic about Root CA installation and Ubuntu on Stack, and someone also said that 'old methods' don't work for him either (also Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 2):

For me, placing a root CA certificate in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and running `update-ca-certificates` works fine. This doesn't affect Firefox or Google Chrome, since they use their own certificate stores, but tools like `wget` work fine.

According to [`man update-ca-certificates`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html):

```
It reads the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf. Each line gives a pathname
of a CA certificate under  /usr/share/ca-certificates  that  should  be
trusted.  Lines that begin with "#" are comment lines and thus ignored.
Lines that begin with "!" are deselected, causing the  deactivation  of
the CA certificate in question. Certificates must have a .crt extension
in order to be included by update-ca-certificates.

Furthermore  all  certificates  with  a  .crt  extension  found   below
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates   are   also  included  as  implicitly
trusted.
```